# Wildcard to Match One Or Zero Characters

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, wildcard

Is there a short hand for this?
Is there a wildcard that matches on any or null?
Another was to say it is match on zero or one.

```
select [id], [word] from [FTSwordDef]
 where [word] like 'system_'
    or [word] like 'system'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a shorter way, but it would likely make your query non-[sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) (unless it is already so):

```
WHERE word + ' ' LIKE 'system_'
```

It works because any extra space on the left side of `LIKE` is disregarded, while, if it is not extra i.e. if it is within the length of the right side's argument, it takes part in matching the pattern string like any other character.

So, for instance, all of the following would result in `true`:

```
(1) 'system ' LIKE 'system_'
(2) 'systemA' LIKE 'system_'
(3) 'systemA ' LIKE 'system_'
```

In (1), the space matches the `_` of the pattern string. In (2), it is `A` that matches the `_`. In `(3)`, it is also `A` while the space is disregarded.

Here's a nice little demo to illustrate this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9521.

Comment: With the problem at hand I cannot really use this but it is an answer to the stated question.

Answer (score 1):

Horribly inefficient and I'd prefer [Andriy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057961/146077), but you could use wildcard and also compare the length.

```
select [id], [word] from [FTSwordDef]
  where [word] like 'system%'
    and LEN([word]) <= LEN('system%')
```

Comment: OK returns the correct answer. But it is not short cut to where [word] like 'system_' or [word] like 'system'

Answer (score -3):

Nope.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

If a percent character won't do, you'll need an OR.  It's an extra part to the clause so yes it's less clean, but using LIKE in the first place introduces inefficiencies anyway.  The rule of thumb is, avoid LIKE if possible, if performance is a concern.

Comment: Because that would also match `system22222`.

Comment: How is nope and avoid LIKE an answer to the question?  Without LIKE 'system_' is evaluated as a literal not a single character wildcard.

Comment: Blam, it's a yes-or-no question and in English, "nope" is a common colloquial form of "no".

Comment: @ty733420 First you recommended %.  Then you recommend not using LIKE.  Without LIKE the wildcard breaks.  Your answer is wrong a second time.

Comment: No.  My answer is right.  There is no wildcard to match one or zero characters.

Comment: @ty733420 You recommended not using LIKE and that breaks it.  That is a wrong answer.

Comment: @Blam: I might be wrong but it really looks like you are interpreting ty733420's suggestion not to use LIKE a little too literally. They seem to be suggesting that you avoid using the *operator* `LIKE` (i.e. that you not use `LIKE 'whatever'` at all) while you seem to understand it that they are telling you to omit just the *keyword* `LIKE` (and break the syntax). I don't know why they are so against the `LIKE` operator *in general* (as it seems), though.